# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm developing a full-stack application using ASP.NET core 5.0 Web Api for the back-end and Angular 12 for the front-end.

When sending a http post request to the back-end I'm getting an error related to CORS policies.

The error is:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5001/api/v1/user/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I looked at this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed, but it did not give me enough information to come up with the solution

I believe my problem might be related to the first bullet point:

> Trying to access an https resource that has an invalid certificate will cause this error

because my front end uses http protocol and my backend uses https protocol.

What is considered a valid certificate?

I also do not have an adblocker installed in my web browser so I can't think of anything else to try as I believe I am enabling CORS in my following code.

Any ideas as to what is going wrong? I could be missing some sort of configuration or something?

---

### Code samples

**Back-end**

*startup.cs*

```
// startup.cs
using MyApi.Installers;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MyApi
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // CORS CONFIGURED HERE           
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsApi",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());
            });

            // This is an extension method that installs swagger, jwt, services, etc...
            // I can add those also if need be
            services.InstallServicesInAssembly(Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            SwaggerOptions swaggerOptions = new SwaggerOptions();
            Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SwaggerOptions)).Bind(swaggerOptions);

            app.UseSwagger(options => options.RouteTemplate = swaggerOptions.JsonRoute);
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint(swaggerOptions.UiEndpoint, swaggerOptions.Description);
                options.RoutePrefix = System.String.Empty;
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            // CORS ENABLED HERE
            app.UseCors("CorsApi");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
        }
    }
}
```

*UserController.cs -> Login function*

```
// UserController.cs -> Login function
        [HttpPost(ApiRoutes.User.Login)]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] UserLoginRequest request)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return BadRequest();
            }

            // Validates users credentials
            if (!_userService.IsValidUserCredentials(request.Email, request.Password))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Ok(});
        }
```

**Front-end**

*auth-service.ts*

```
// auth.service.ts
export class AuthService {

  private readonly baseUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api/v1';

  // Adds CORS header to the request?
  private httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type':'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origins':'*'})};

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('email', email);
    postData.append('password', password);

    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/user/login`, postData, this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

*login.component.ts*

```
// login.component.ts
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required])],
    password: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  get f() {
    return this.loginForm.controls;
  }

  login(form: FormGroup): void {
    // These output in console window
    console.log(this.f.email.value);
    console.log(this.f.password.value);

    // Error here
    this.authService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value).subscribe(
      response => {
        // This does not get output
        console.log(response);
        //this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

}
```

---

I've tried to make the code as simple as possible.

Edit: forgot to mention I've also enabled this:
[image]

Comment: in your configureservices try this    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
            });   and in your configure try this     app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders"); should be first line, and in your controller try this  [EnableCors("AllowAllHeaders")]

Comment: @Nonik I tried what you said and got a 500 error and it told me that app.UseCors() must come between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(). I put it in between to try again, but then went back to the 400 error. Thank you for trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I can't necessarily explain *why* this solved my problem but it did...

In chrome I also went to: chrome://settings/security -> Manage certificates -> remove localhost certificate.

Then in Visual Studio terminal run the command: dotnet dev-certs https --trust

After the following works

In Startup.cs:

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
```

In startup.cs -> ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
        );
});
```

In Startup.cs -> Configure:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
// ... 
// UseCors must be between routing and endpoints
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
// ...
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place UseCors between UseRouting and UseAuthorization

```
 app.UseRouting();
 app.UseCors("CorsApi");
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

try this syntax for AddCors

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsApi", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

and maybe if it still is not working, remove this too

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origins':'*'
```

Comment: Tried both of those ideas and the same issue still ocurs, but thank you.