# Firefox Throws Error When Installing Fabric Chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am currently developing a tool which takes required configuration information from the user via a GUI and creates a local fabric test network according to the given information. The backend and GUI both run in the localhost. The app also has features like installing, approving and committing chaincodes, joining channels, creating ca or peer nodes. The tech stack is as follows;

- GUI: Vue.js 3
- Backend: Node 14 LTS
- Fabric: 2.3.1
- Ubuntu: 20.04

My problem is when I am installing a chaincode to a peer Firefox throws the following error;
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/prepareCommit. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`
The strange thing is that I handle cors issues in my backend (using cors packege with express.js) and only when the code hits where I call `peer lifecycle chaincode install` firefox throws this error. But when I disable the line where I call install command or I run another command like `peer channel list` Firefox does not throw any error. Also this error does not happen when I test with Chrome or Postman.

My Firefox version: 92.0(64-bit) for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0
Full Error Messages:

- Browser: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/prepareCommit. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`
- Client Code: `Type-Error: Network Error when attempting to fetch resources`

The MDN docs say that it is possible addons, adblockers or extensions might be causing this since the error message indicates the error happened either network or protocol level. So here are the things I have tried;

- Run firefox in the troubleshoot mode (Still threw the error)
- Test using CHROME and POSTMAN (No error occurred)
- Run different code other than `peer lifecycle chaincode install`  such as `peer channel list` (No error)
- Make the code wait 120 seconds in order to eliminate timeout related issues (No error)

I don't come across this issue when running other peer commands. So my belief is that `peer lifecycle chaincode install` command somehow breaks the connection between firefox and my server. Is there anyone who has any idea what the cause of this error might be? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Cross-origin-request blocked". How to overcome that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666849/cross-origin-request-blocked-how-to-overcome-that)

Comment: No it does not. As I said it is not a cors issue. I handle it in the backend and all other requests succeed as well as this one when I comment out the `peer lifecycle chaincode install`.  I still tried what it says in the question you posted and it is no good. 

I basically run a bunch of bash commands as child processes from a node program that is hosted on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine. These commands are triggered from a client application via http. My observation is that one specific command breaks the connection between Firefox browser and my express app.

Comment: The error message is crystal clear. There are no many causes of such error. You need to take a look at how the routing is working in your application. This other question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67593329/cross-origin-request-blocked-reason-cors-request-did-not-succeed